# Situación con ModuleNotFoundError: No module named en python

Tags: python

estoy utilizando python3 tengo 2 archivos y estoy tratando de importar uno de ellos dentro del otro.

Las rutas están así:

```
C:\libredte-sdk-python-master

C:\ejemplos\001-generar_dte.py

C:\libredte-sdk-python-master\libredte\__init__.py

C:\libredte-sdk-python-master\libredte\sdk.py
```

Como podrán ver sdk y **init** están en la misma carpeta.

En el archivo 001-generar_dte.py hago lo siguiente:

```
# módulos que se usarán
from os import sys
from libredte.sdk import LibreDTE
```

Como pueden ver de la carpeta de ejemplos subo un piso y luego voy a la carpeta libredte y luego al archivo sdk y de esta forma poder importar la clase LibreDTE pero al hacer ello muestra lo siguiente:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libredte'
```

y no entiendo por qué? cuál es el problema allí? Gracias.

Comment: as intentado ejecutar un `pip install libredte.api-client` o`pip3 install libredte.api-client` desde la linea de comando de tu sistema operativo?

Comment: @Bryro ok lo hice y me instalo algo pero ahora como importo la clase LibreDTE() ?